# How to build Glog successfully on VS2015 or cmake?

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2015, cmake, glog

I am using windows 10 x64 visual studio 2015, I have downloaded opencv successfully and want to download the sfm module, from the libraries that I need to download is Glog, this is the only library presenting a big issue and I tried many ways but it is still failing even in later steps
First I have followed the instruction in the following tutorial:

[[Installation Guides] Building OpenCV 3.1 SfM sample code in Windows 10 with MSVC 2015](https://gist.github.com/jack06215/878a2cc8f0c1f111313ba0a1cfd86bb3#file-readme-md)

When build the solution file I get large number of syntax errors that I believe may be due to the fact that these projects are of vcproj which may be older than VS2008 and have failed.

I even tried to fix the logging.cc file beforehand and then running the file but there are still build error.

Instead I tried to build the file on cmake, and adding gflags directory
 after opening the project, I built it and I got the following message

> Unable to start program 'C:\build_glog\x64\Release\ALL_BUILD'.
>
> Access is denied.

[image]

I searched for solutions to it but couldn’t come up with any successful built

Is there anybody that can help me in this I tried several versions of Glog and always a problem, or anybody has made a successful built for the glog on VS2015 x64 release and can send me their file.

Comment: It looks more like a permission problem. Try running the app from outside visual studio. It should something similar. If that is the case try running it with administrator rights. If it works then it is a permission problem indeed.

Comment: I just tried that unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the problem still same error but thank you

Comment: ALL_BUILD is a symbolic target from CMake and is not connected to an executable in the solution. Select another target that builds an executable in the Visual Studio and choose `Set as StartUp Project` from the context menu.